# How to extend PageView to both sides with builder?

Tags: dart, flutter

Using `PageView.builder` I can get an infinite list of pages, but only in one direction, i.e. it is finite in the other direction!

The default `scrollDirection` of a `PageView` is `Axis.horizontal`. So what I mean is that in the regular case I can only scroll infinitely to the right, but not to the left.

[image: illustration]

I want to be able *to scroll infinitely in **both directions***. I have not found a way to do this, especially, because I would expect the `itemBuilder` to give out negative indices then, which I have never seen. That leads me to wondering whether this is implemented at all, but I am open to custom solutions and will try to come up with something aswell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it pretty straight forward. Honestly, I must have been out of my mind writing the question and issueing the bounty.

```
// number is irrelevant
final initialPage = (
    .161251195141521521142025 // :)
    * 1e6,).round();
final itemCount = getSomeItemCount();

PageView.builder(
  pageController: PageController(
    initialPage: initialPage,
  ),
  itemBuilder: (context, page) {
    final index = itemCount - (initialPage - page - 1) % itemCount - 1;
    return getPageContent(index);
  },
);
```

I am not sure if I should give credit to [Rémi Rousselet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8394265/r%c3%a9mi-rousselet) because I was using this method before he proposed his answer. I just wanted to mention him because this question is getting undeserved traffic and he helped me to solve my problem :)

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind `final initialPage = (.161251195141521521142025 * 1e6,).round();`?

Comment: @sudoExclaimationExclaimation It is simply an arbitrary five-digit number.

Answer (score 15):

There's no *official* way of having an infinite scroll in both directions.

But you can instead use `PageController`'s `initialPage` property. Setting it to an absurdly big value. And then use this value as your "index 0".

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController pageController = new PageController(initialPage: 4242);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(body: new PageView.builder(
      controller: pageController,
      itemBuilder: (context, _index) {
        final index =  _index - 4242;
        return new Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
          color: Colors.red,
          child: new Center(
            child: new Text(index.toString()),
          ),
        );
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought about this aswell. Only problem I am facing is how I get some kind of loop, where I scroll to the left and "get back" to the right, as if it was a ring. I will just create my own `Widget` for this.

Comment: You can just use the modulo operator and a simple math : `if (index < 0) index = itemCount + index`. That's not in your question though

Comment: You asked for negative indice. `I would expect the itemBuilder to give out negative indices then`

Comment: Don't worry. It's not like I care about bounty anymore anyway. I'm at 7k afterall haha

Comment: Is the answer still valid today or does PageView handle negative ranges now?

Comment: @user3612643  year 2023 and it still seems to be the solution.... :(